# Swift: Not initialised Lazy Variable that returns Closure

Tags: swift, closures, lazy-initialization

I have a lazy variable that is **not** initialised:

```
lazy var time: () -> String = {
    return String(describing: Date())
}
```

Whenever I call `time()` I get a new Date. So it seems like it behaves exactly like:

```
var time: () -> String {
    return {
        return String(describing: Date())
    }
}
```

In this context, is it bad practice just to use the lazy closure, because then I don't have to write two `return`-statements in a row or do I miss something?

Comment: Your  `lazy var time` is initialized *only once* – to a closure that, when called, returns a string with the current date.

Comment: @MartinR So in this case, since the content of the closure is still dynamic, it is basically a function that I can pass around?

Comment: Why not just say `func time() -> String { return String(describing: Date()) }`?

Comment: Functions *are* closures in Swift. – What behavior is it that you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Hamish Well, my original code sample is a bit more complicated. The closure must be passed around and stored in an array. So a normal variable is not sufficient enough.

Comment: @MartinR Haha thanks a lot for your statement "Functions are closures". Now I noticed the first time, that I can store functions in an array and call them afterwards xD Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two return statements in a row nor do you need a lazy closure. Why not just do:

```
let time: () -> String = {
    return String(describing: Date())
}
```

Or just replace this whole thing with a method:

```
func time() -> String {
    return String(describing: Date())
}
```

One reason why you might want to use a closure here is that you want other parts of your code to change the value of the closure. If that's the case, just do it like the first snippet, otherwise I don't think anything is preventing you from writing a method. You can pass a method around just like a closure, because methods *are* a kind of closure!

Lazy variables are really needed when initializing them takes much resources. Creating closures tend to be cheap.

Comment: Just to amplify the point here: it is bad practice to make this `lazy` and it's bad practice to make it a property. It should be a function, as in the last example. It's bad practice to make it `lazy` because there's no reason to delay the initialization. (It's like writing `lazy var x = 4`; it's legal but pointless.) It shouldn't be a property because it doesn't act like a property. Despite nothing changing about the struct, the value is different every time it's called. This isn't "property-like."

Comment: Converting `Date` to `String` using `String(describing:)` should only be used when debugging. Never do that for any other situation. Use a `DateFormatter` for all other cases. Use `date/timeStyle` if showing the date to a user. Use `dateFormat` if a fixed format is needed to send to a server, for example.

Comment: @maddy You're right. I just chose this example for simplicity reasons, to demonstrate that the content of lazy is not stored like it would be, if the lazy variable would have returned a non closure.